# Object with special character "/" produces Automation Error in GetObject

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory

We have an old Microsoft Access font end that serves as the GUI to our user database. I was never much of a VBA person so as I go through fixing bugs I'm learning as I go.

Our Access DB has a number of commands to sync info to Active Directory. One such command is to add a user to a group. However, whenever the group contains a `/` the group is never added.

The debug produces this as:

> Run-time error -2147463168 (80005000)': Automation Error".

Printing out the targetgroup shows the DN as I expect it. Trying to escape the `/` before the GetObject doesn't help and causes its own auth error.

Here's the top part of the function -

```
Function AddGroup(TargetGroup, strUserID, Optional strOptReqBy)
    Dim objDL
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & GetDName(CStr(strUserID)))

        Set objDL = GetObject("LDAP://" & TargetGroup)
        On Error Resume Next
        objDL.Add (objUser.ADsPath)
        objDL.SetInfo
        On Error GoTo 0
```

This works fine if the group does not contain a `/`.
Debug points to `Set objDL = GetObject("LDAP://" & TargetGroup)`

Looking for some input on why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to escape the `/` ?  https://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams You know, looking at it now I think I had a complete brain fart. I was escaping with Chr(34) based on other stuff I found. Your link was awesome.

Going to give this a try tomorrow, for now going to see if I can find a better way to do it than just using REPLACE()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an LDAP path, the `/` is a separator. Not only is the `//` used near the beginning, but you can also specify the server you want to connect to, followed by a `/`, then the DN of the object, like this:

```
LDAP://example.com/DC=example,DC=com
```

That's necessary if the computer you're running this from isn't not joined to the same (or trusted) domain than the domain you're connecting to.

So that means that if the DN of the object you want to bind to has a `/`, it will think that everything before the `/` is a server to connect to and it explodes.

So you just need to escape it, which, as you've already learned, is done with a `\`:

```
LDAP://OU=This\/That,DC=example,DC=com
```

So yeah, a simple replace will do:

```vb
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & Replace(GetDName(CStr(strUserID)), "/", "\/")
```

Don't feel bad. Even Microsoft [has this bug in their code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29090).

Comment: Was able to update both our group addition and removal when escaping the Target group. Thanks my dude!